# Error in sortedXyData using R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset composed of observations `X`, regressors `X` and grouping variables `group`.

Link to the dataset : [data.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i31eradkykbjoja/data.txt)

Using the library `nlme`, I can build a dataframe with :

```
ex1 <- groupedData(Y ~ X | group,data=mydata)
```

After that, I would like to apply the function `sortedXyData` in order to sort my data with respect to `X`. When I try

```
sortedXyData("X","Y",ex1)
```

I get the following error :

```
[1] x y
<0 lignes> (ou 'row.names' de longueur nulle)
Message d'avis :
In sortedXyData.default("X", "Y", ex1) :
NAs introduits lors de la conversion automatique
```

But if I try with a much simpler dataset such as :

```
X <- c(1.2,2.2,3.5,-3.8,9,3.7,4,8,7)
Y <- c(5,4,8,3,6,2,0,5,5)
group <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
group <- as.factor(group)
data1 <- data.frame(X,Y,group)
data2 <- groupedData(Y ~ X | group,data=data1)
sortedXyData("X","Y",data2)
```

then, the output is :

```
  x y
1 4 0
2 7 5
3 8 5
4 9 6
Message d'avis :
In sortedXyData.default("X", "Y", data2) :
  NAs introduits lors de la conversion automatique
```

We can see that the integer values in `X` are sorted but not the decimal values. It seems the problem comes from the way R deals with these values. I don't know what to do in order to have all the values in `X` sorted.

Comment: Unless it's a typo, the error message follows columns named 'x' and 'y' but your input was supposed to be 'X' and 'Y' (upper vs. lower case). Did you double-check that your `mydata` has the list elements you expect, etc?

Comment: Yes, `mydata` contains colums `X` and `Y` (in capital letters).

Comment: Please use dputdput and post a reproducible set of data, as the posted vectors appear to have mismatched lengths (and if I trim them, no errors)

Comment: I added a link to my dataset. `X`, `Y` both have the same length (565).

Comment: Any idea of what could be wrong with this function or with the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something wrong with your setup, or you are not posting exactly what you did.
If I run your simple data set, I get proper sorting:

```
sortedXyData("X","Y",data2)
     x y
1 -3.8 3
2  1.2 5
3  2.2 4
4  3.5 8
5  3.7 2
6  4.0 0
7  7.0 5
8  8.0 5
9  9.0 6
```

Make sure you have the latest version of `R` and of the packages in use.

Comment: You're right ! The problem comes from the version of R. On the `version 3.1.0 Patched (2014-04-10 r65396) -- "Spring Dance"` the function `sortedXyData` is not working well but it is working fine on `R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)`.